# how to replace value with spesific column with searching id on array

Tags: php, arrays, replace

i have some problem with data array, how to replace spesific array column with searching in column id in array

data json array like this :

```
$json ='
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Eko","approved":"n"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Rudi","approved":"n"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Yanto","approved":"n"}
]
';
```

ihave tried many tutorial but not spesific replace array

iwant output like this :

```
$json =
'
   [
        {"id":1,"name":"Eko","approved":"n"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Rudi","approved":"y"},
        {"id":3,"name":"Yanto","approved":"n"}
    ]
';
```

i apreciate with your help

defferent is **"approved":"y"** in json2

Comment: "approved":"y" that is defferent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($json);

foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
   if($item->id == $your_serach_id){
       $array[$key]->approved = "y";
   }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can tirverse the JSON object using for loop or foreach look and fetch the key value pair in the array and for getting your desired output you will need to know the value of which key you have to change so in the loop you can `array[i] ->key = new_value`this line should be thier after if condition in for loop

Comment: yes that is json string, i have tried to json_decode and than searching by the id 2 but how to update the value "y" in id json_decode $json